# How to connect to internet from recovery mode?

Tags: internet, recovery-mode

I am working on a kernel panic issue.

As Ubuntu is very reliant on internet, I am currently investigating how to connect to internet when choosing recovery mode. Even in my healthy 11.10 system it doesnt work (nor wireless, nor wired). I ticked for both cases available for all users.

Normally, in recovery mode the netroot option should give you access to the internet, but no joy. Any idea?

Comment: If you just want to enable wireless in recovery it's covered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/104066/enable-wi-fi-in-recovery-terminal ...

Answer (score 8):

When you boot to recovery mode you should get an option to drop to a root shell with networking , `netroot`

[image: netroot]

I do not know what problem you are having, but sometimes it is easier to use the live CD.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

If needed you can use `chroot` to access / update your root partition.

Assuming your ubuntu partition is as /dev/sda1 (you may need to mount /home and/or /boot if you have separate /home or /boot partitions) ...

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# If needed
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot

sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
sudo cp /etc/hosts mnt/etc/

sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev

sudo chroot /mnt

mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
```

You should now have root access to your ubuntu root partition.