# Enable Wi-Fi in Recovery Terminal

Tags: wireless, command-line, fglrx, data-recovery

How do I enable WiFi from the Ubuntu 11.10 `netroot` recovery terminal?

After just 12 hours with Ubuntu, I managed to destroy my ATI fglrx drivers and now I can't repair them without Internet access.

Comment: Connecting to WiFi via the recovery terminal is different than connecting to Starbucks' WiFi via a normal terminal.

Answer (score 26):

What worked for me was `sudo service network-manager start`.

Comment: Really good! :)

Comment: Good , in my case I had to write NetworkManager instead

Answer (score 12):

First, run `ifconfig wlan0 up`. This will enable wireless. You won't get any feedback unless there's a problem. Next, run `iwlist wlan0 scan` to scan for nearby wireless networks. Once you have looked at the output and know which wireless network you want to connect to, run `iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key s:WIRELESS_KEY`, replacing NETWORK_ID with the name (essid) of the nework and WIRELESS_KEY with the network passcode. Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't work since `ifconfig` is not installed by default anymore. So on a fresh install of Ubuntu, you would be screwed.

Comment: The easiest way to setup the wireless in command line in ubuntu is with the `nmcli` tool ( the network manager command line ).
See basic operations in the documentation: https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections

Answer (score 0):

as of January 2023, you can enter the root shell via recovery mode and then, `nmcli` is the tool you want to use, make changes and do the repair - persists whatever changes you make otherwise they are of no use