# After installing Nvidia driver I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'" error in Python3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, tkinter

I tried to install the Nvidia driver (sudo apt-get install nvidia-390) for AI calculations on GPU in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. The installation works, but afterwards python3 is not working and giving the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'", but of course tkinter is installed and can not be reinstalled. I have a notebook with GT 740M graphics card. Any ideas how to get the graphics card running and also python3 running?

Comment: But do you have python3-tk installed?

Comment: yes. And the same python program worked before installing the driver...

Comment: Actually I figured out you are right, it was not installed. It was installed on my previous Ubuntu 16.04 and still did not work. As everywhere is written tkinter is part of python, I assumed it was installed by default on 18.04. However it was not installed and installing it of course made it work. Thank you!

Comment: I made an instruction how it worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033489/the-easy-way-install-nvidia-drivers-cuda-cudnn-and-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-1