# Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS Live USB boots to black screen

Tags: live-usb, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

I am trying to install Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS since the first point release is now available.

(My starting point is Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

I thought that a sensible first step would be to try a live USB, and it seems that there is some weird issue between my PC and the live USB.

System info (via Neofetch):

```
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              iain@iain-BB-X001783 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           -------------------- 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Host: BB-X001783 V1.0 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Kernel: 5.15.0-46 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Uptime: 5 mins 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Packages: 4310 (dpkg), 35 (snap) 
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   Resolution: 3840x2160 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   DE: Xfce 4.16 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   WM Theme: Greybird 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3] 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/3] 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      Terminal Font: DejaVu Sans Mono 9 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 (12) @ 3.400GHz 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P400 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           Memory: 2106MiB / 15945MiB 
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

The behaviour I observe, is that upon attempting to boot, I progress through the initial BIOS/UEFI related screens, and then I just get a completely black screen, with a 'stuck' mouse pointer (I've waited up to ten minutes for something else to happen, which I think *should* be plenty) [3].  I've tried shutting down and rebooting a number of times now, and always get the same result.

The downloaded image verified OK [2], and I created the USB with 'Startup Disk Creator' [.1], so I'm not sure what else I could/should have done. Unfortunately I only have a single USB stick that's big enough to take the image, so I can't simply try alternative hardware, just in case that's the reason.

Does anyone have any idea of something I can try to debug what's going wrong please?  Am I being too impatient with 'only' waiting 10 minutes?

**Edits/Further info**

1: Tried to use a different USB writer (balenaEtcher), which reported that the image was written OK, yet gives the same result.

2: By "image verified OK" I mean that SHA256 signature has been verified with sha256sum.

3: Image of screen after 10 minute wait is below, mouse and keyboard are unresponsive to input at this point.

[image: Screen when issue occurs]

Comment: Did you reflash or use a different flashing program? Etcher is the flashing program referenced in the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). It will automatically verify the integrity of the *flash* to USB.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I followed the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick that say to use Startup Disk Creator.  I'll try Etcher instead...

Comment: (And FWIW, the instructions here also say to use Startup Disk Creator: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview )

Comment: @Nmath same result with Etcher

Comment: @IainCunningham Can you verify your ISO integrity using sha256sum and make sure that the file isn't corrupted?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 "The downloaded image verified OK" - already done

Comment: "GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P400" makes me suspect problems with the graphics. Please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: @sudodus We have a winner(-ish), your comment led me to select "the safe graphics" option from the grub menu and that has worked beautifully.

Comment: That's good :-) When installed, you should also use `nomodeset` and then try 1. if there is an automatically selected proprietary nvidia driver, that works with your card; 2. or if still problems, try some of the other nvidia proprietary drivers. I hope that you will find a driver, that releases the full power of the graphics card.

Comment: Yes, used, `nomodeset` and then used the `ubuntu-drivers` method  to get everything up and running. :-)  [The ubuntu-drivers method, in case anyone is wondering: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033489/the-easy-way-install-nvidia-drivers-cuda-cudnn-and-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-1/1033498#1033498 ]