# Why does CTRL-ALT-F1 not send me to a terminal?

Tags: window-manager

I'd like to go to a terminal so I can kill processes jamming my windowing session. (I would then return with  CTRL-ALT-F7.) But  CTRL-ALT-F1 just locks the screen; no terminal.

CTRL-ALT-Fn-F1  similarly does not work.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the effect of  CTRL-ALT-F1?

(This is  a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming with  Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Usual way to open terminal is Ctrl Alt t surely?

Comment: tty's showing a login depends on the graphics card driver.  Switch to another driver and try again.

Comment: @graham I am doing this when my windwoing session  jams up. I need some sort of override key that has higher priority than the processes using 100% of CPU or memory.

Comment: >  "Switch to another driver"
I have an Nvidia card that produces horrible problems with the wrong driver.

Comment: Thank you. This one  was useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033206

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CTRL-ALT-F3 to get to terminal; ALT-F2 to return to GUI. ([See this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033206/))
I have not yet verified if this has a higher priority  that would  override a stuck windowing system, thus allowing me to get to a terminal, then kill  the problematic process, comparable to Windows CTRL-ALT-DEL.

Comment: Nah, none of the F1-F12 works.

Comment: Appparently ctrl+alt+del works to reboot, but ctrl+alt+f1 doesn't send me to a tty1. And my gdm session crashed (somehow) so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @isaaclw Note that the answer says to use Ctrl+Alt+F3, not Ctrl+Alt+F1.