# Uninstalling python uninstalled everything that depended on it

Tags: python

I uninstalled Python with `sudo apt remove python3` and it removed every package that depended on Python (I think).

Now I can't do anything on my system, including opening gnome-terminal. Is there a way to salvage this?

Comment: Ubuntu depends on Python scripts. Without python, as you've discovered, nothing works. You broke your system. Restore from backup or carefully reinstall. You MAY be able to preserve `/HOME`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/a/416691) (Also, if you have trouble switching to the terminal, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033206/switch-to-console-in-ubuntu-18-04-how-to-leave-gui))

Comment: Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecouverable error. You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.

Comment: JC...What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecoverable error. You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.