# Can't push Django project to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I ran into a issue with Django pushing to heroku because of
Python version, when I change in my terminal with `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python` changing the 3.6 to other versions installed and clearing all python alternatives. Now when installing a new application in the terminal I get errors.

[image: errors I receive]

Comment: Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecoverable error. You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330994/uninstalling-python-uninstalled-everything-that-depended-on-it/1331062#1331062

Comment: Okay let me try out this method, hoping it will work