# Keyboard Stops working after flashing not allowed sign

Tags: keyboard, onscreen-keyboard

I have been using Ubuntu from last 2 years and i don't know from where this problem suddenly arises.
My keyboard is working fine on login screen of Ubuntu and lets me in. But after entering desktop environment **not allowed sign** starts flashing and pointer(where i have to type) starts blinking and I'm unable to type. I used external keyboard also, the problem still persists.
On Screen keyboard is also showing same behavior. I have checked it in other Linux os also, problem is there also.
I thought there would be some hardware problem, went to service center, he said keyboard is absolutely fine.
After that I installed window and this problem never happened there. But about 4 to 5 days back I switched to Ubuntu again, the same old problem arised.

Please help me in this. This is irritating. I don't want to switch to windows.

Comment: I don't really understand where the problem arises... You log in, and then the desktop environment appears, or not ? What DE is it (Gnome ? KDE ? ...). Or is it just a black screen with garbage ? Did reinstall Ubuntu after testing with Windows or was it double boot ? Can you log in a console (Ctrl+Alt+F3 for example) ? ...

Comment: Desktop environment does appear. Every application is working fine. Just keyboard is not working after that 'not allowed sign' flashes. And this is happening only on linux, on Windows keyboard is working fine.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I see a "not allowed sign" when my Bluetooth speaker is switched off. Maybe, for some reason, your keyboard gets switched off, deactived, disconnected or something like that after login. Maybe another keyboard (or a device that "thinks" it's a keyboard?) kicks it off?

Comment: But the problem is not with Windows.

Comment: Should add computer make and model, and of keyboard if different to your question.  Problem sounds like it might be an updated driver issue if had no problem last two years with same keyboard and version of Ubuntu, advise if either of these two have changed recently.

Comment: It is Hp Envy Notebook-14. This problem arised when I was using 18.04. I installed 19.04, problem was there too. Then I switched to windows. Now again I installed 20.04, and same problem.

Comment: This link sounds like your problem, so hopefully it will help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/keyboard-not-working-after-update-to-18-04  Read all before trying answers, some are quite simple.

Comment: Thank you all. But nothing worked. I switched back to Windows.