# 20.04 Mouse click and keyboard unresponsive

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse

Before logging in, I can move the mouse to top right and select power off or reboot. But after logging in, no click, either right or left, is effective.

The keyboard does not accept input after logging in, except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

I can get to a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to issue commands.

Any suggestions on what I might try to fix this issue? I am lost.

Comment: See whether it is due to the account by creating a new account and see if this issue persists in a fresh account.

Comment: No, the result is the same behavior as the first account.

Comment: Check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/keyboard-not-working-after-update-to-18-04

Comment: And eventually also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105862/laptop-keyboard-not-working-properly-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` at CTRL-ALT-F3 did not change behavior

Comment: I also did this same command after booting to root from grub - problem not fixed

Comment: Yes, I tried all of the above but no luck. I was desperate and re-installed the OS.

Answer (score 2):

## Replace the screen saver

I experienced something similar on Xubuntu LTS 20.04 with the keys of my [Logitech K400 Plus wireless touch keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400-plus) becoming unresponsive after a while except for console switching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F6</kbd>.

As it turned out, the buggy `xfce4-screensaver` was kicking in. I replaced it with the more reliable `xscreensaver`.

```
$ sudo apt remove xfce4-screensaver
$ sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

I would suggest replacing your current screensaver with `xscreensaver`.

Comment: Thank you Serge, that was exactly my problem too. So I removed xfce4-screensaver. Why would I not install xscreensaver? Anyhow, I can confirm that this is a good solution, with the background Xubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-52-generic, fresh install without any added software, installed and updated today, on Asrock B550 with AMD 4650G.

Answer (score 0):

## Remove the screensaver

In addition, the [Xubuntu mailinglist](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/xubuntu-users/2020-October/011485.html) offered an alternative, i.e. not using a screensaver at all. The steps are:

```
sudo apt remove xfce4-screensaver
```

Next, disable start on login of xfce4-screensaver: In Xubuntu it is Whisker > Settings > Session and Startup > [] Screensaver (launch screensaver and locker program)

Finally:

```
xfce4-screensaver-command --exit
```

It also should be noted that turning off a screensaver involves setting power manager, turning display power management on (yes, not off) and move the sliders to never blank.