# Xubuntu 20.4 LTS no window decorations, no keyboard, no mouse

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, mouse, window-manager

Suddenly my Xubuntu 20.04 installation went wrong: it boots, but it does not react to keyboard and the mouse pointer is not shown. The taskbar and the start button is visible. With <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> I can activate the start button, but can't enter anything into it's search box.

I tried to replace the screensaver according to this post:

[20.04 Mouse click and keyboard unresponsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261848/20-04-mouse-click-and-keyboard-unresponsive)

But it didn't help.

I can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1...F7</kbd> and can change to console, and can shut down or reboot it.

I suspect that the window manager is screwed up somehow.

Is there a way to fix it without reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted xfwm4 via "alt + F2" according to this thread:

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5806

After rebooting everything seems working as before (keyboard, mouse, window decoration). Probably the xsession cache became garbled on the machine.