# Built-in Laptop Keyboard not working today on HP Convertible x360 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, xorg

Built-in Laptop Keyboard not working today on HP Convertible x360 with Ubuntu 18.04.
I have tried the `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` using the on-screen keyboard, followed by a reboot, but to no avail.

What else should I try to get the built-in keyboard of my laptop to work ??

- I really want to continue using Ubuntu (because Windows is soooo slow).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the newer kernels are not seeing some laptop keyboards, been mainly Acers.  Wireless keyboards seem to work if one is handy, or need to use recovery option and use an earlier kernel.  Kernels this is happening on seem to be 5.4.0-44 and/or 0-45.  Can also see this link, some answers to do with HP and 18.04.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/keyboard-not-working-after-update-to-18-04?rq=1

Comment: Have also seen above command, but with   --reinstall   added after install.  Have not used it yet, on different laptop.

Comment: Hello crip659:I get the following when I use --reinstall added after install:sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all:-           <pre>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-all--reinstall
</pre>

Comment: I have had some success when I boot by choosing the second option (Advanced Ubuntu) and then selecting "linux 5.4.0-42-generic" instead of [linux 5.4.0-45-generic]  I have my built-in keyboard back using 42 instead of 45.   My s/w update has just advised me of new updates - I think I'll wait !

Comment: Does anyone know if the latest software updates will fix the [keyboard not working] issue under {linux 5.4.0-45-generic} ??

Comment: It is ```sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all```.  Not sure if it works any better though.

Comment: I am currently using the recovery option and selecting linux 5.4.0-42 generic to get around this issue - Does anyone have an idea when this might be fixed ?

Comment: I have since upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 but find the same issue with kernels 5.4.0-45 and 5.4.0-49.  I am still selecting linux 5.4.0-42 generic to get around this frustrating issue on my hp-convertible-x360.

Comment: New answer to this problem, see link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20?noredirect=1#comment2172529_1280217