# Broken update and package mess: how do I remove old packages manually?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade

After a `do-release-upgrade` to switch from 16.04 to 18.04, something failed and machine was left in a "in between" state, with lots of broken dependencies issues. My package tree is a mess, I am desperate... ;-)

I tried lots of things (including `dpkg --configure -a`, randomly removing packages with `dpkg --force depends -P <pkg-name>`, plus other things), but I am kinda stuck at present.

So, when I try:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   (here 20 lines)
The following additional packages will be installed:
... (here 5 lines)
 Suggested packages:
 ... more
Recommended packages:
 ... more
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 ... more
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 ... more (10 lines)
28 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 327 not upgraded.
228 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2 771 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Up to here, nothing I am afraid of. But now, entering `Y`:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 977800 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~18.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 9, in <module>
    from uaclient import gpg
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/gpg.py", line 3, in <module>
    import shutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shutil'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--remove):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So this sounds like a Python error, from what I understand, it can't find `shutil`.
So I manually downloaded what I thought was the thing:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size
and installed manually with:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size_1.0.0-5_all.deb
```

But doing `apt --fix-broken install` again ends up at the same point.

I have limited knowledge with Python, so I can't be sure this is the real issue, but any help is welcome. Else, next step will be probably reinstalling from scratch, but I'd really prefer to avoid that.

At present I am able to manually install packages (download from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ then `dpkg -i`) but that's about it, everything else fails.

For example, if I try to install `libpython3.6-stdlib`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-stdlib
```

I get:

```
libpython3.6-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4) but 3.6.13-1+xenial2 is to be installed
```

which means that I **still** have packages from 16.04 (Xenial).

How can I manually **remove** all the 16.04 packages?

Additional info (machine now boots only with a console):

- `$ python --version` =>  Python 3.6.13
- `$ lsb_release -a` is not available
- `$ uname -a` tells me its a 4.15 kernel (which seem consistent with 18.04)

Comment: Commands like `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` should help.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, I did try dist-upgrade, but failed due to broken dependencies. Didn't known about the second one, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW:
The key point was in fact here:

```
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--remove):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

The whole process failed because of the failure of the "pre-removal" script for the package `ubuntu-advantage-tools` (no idea what that thing is!).

So I did:

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm_OLD
```

and I was able to complete the `sudo apt --fix-broken install` command.

Reboot, then another issue (keyboard unrecognized) that was solved using [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/), after booting in recovery mode:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Was finally able to boot graphically, but... still some issues with package manager still referencing xenial (16.04). I'll post another question.

Comment: Finally fixed everything. With the help of `dpkg -l | grep python*`, I removed all the old python packages identified as 16.04 (or even some 14.04!), using `dpkg --remove <pkgname>`.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like one very sick system; you might want to take it out of its misery, i.e. reinstall. If you don't have a separate `/home` filesystem already, copy your home directory and everything that you put work into away and start over to get a clean system again.

I'd also copy `/etc` away just in case some non-trivial configuration file is worthwhile rescuing (but I'd hold back  copying it to the new system unless absolutely necessary).

Think of it this way: That system served you well for long years (some time just after 2016 since it's a 16.04); let it rest in peace. ;-) Now it's time for something new and clean.

I once made a checklist for myself what stuff I do to a freshly installed Ubuntu to get it into a shape that I find best usable; maybe you can draw some inspiration from it: https://github.com/shundhammer/huha-linux-tips/blob/master/doc/ubuntu-tips.md (some parts may be slightly outdated; nevermind)

Comment: Indeed, very sick system! Actually that machine was even running 14.04 before that, so yeah, quite old.But I wont let go, I'm still trying things ;-) And thanks for that checklist, nice ideas there.