# Issue with removing ubuntu-advantage-tools (28.1~22.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

So I did an upgrade form ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 which did not quite go perfectly and there were some issues. While doing a  `sudo apt-get upgrade` I am getting the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (>= 3.10.6-1~) but it is not installed
 python3-update-manager : Depends: python3-distupgrade but it is not installed
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.13-1+focal1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then when I did a `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I got the following message

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libpython3-stdlib lsb-release python3 python3-apt python3-distro-info python3-pkg-resources python3-update-manager
  python3-xkit python3-yaml python3.10 ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 11 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4,073 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 261415 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-advantage-tools (28.1~22.04) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 14, in <module>
    import apt  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from apt.package import Package as Package, Version as Version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 32, in <module>
    from http.client import BadStatusLine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--remove):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d returned 101, not running 'start ua-timer.timer'
/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d returned 101, not running 'start ubuntu-advantage.service'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think there were some issues with `dkpg` package which is probably causing this issue. I tried to fix it using methods mentioned in other posts about dkpg but no luck. I am not very good with `linux` os either. Any help to resolve this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is with `ubuntu-advantage-tools` as can be noted from this line `Removing ubuntu-advantage-tools (28.1~22.04)` So after a couple of days of googling I found this helpful post [Broken update and package mess: how do I remove old packages manually?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346097/broken-update-and-package-mess-how-do-i-remove-old-packages-manually) which helped to resolve the issue. Essentially running the `sudo mv` command and then a bunch of times `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt autoremove` removed most of the issues

But there were still some issues with `libpython3.10-stdlib` package which was not getting sorted out. Then I cam acorss another helpful post [Unmet dependencies for python 3.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402456/unmet-dependencies-for-python-3-10) and followed the instructions and then folowed up with the update, upgrade and autoremove command and that sorted out all the existing issues. All packages are upto date now