# Wubi install does not load

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, boot-failure

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to install it along side Windows, so I can get the hang of it.

I installed it using Wubi, I then chose to run Ubuntu from the boot menu it does then I get 2 options:

- generic and recovery.

If choose the generic version but it doesn't load up at all. Just wondering what I did wrong or whats happening. I left my PC running for an hour with the purple screen to see if it was just setting up, nothing happens.

Also I am getting error readings when trying to create a disc , with "Nero burn" and "Windows-Disc-Burner". I am trying to install 11.10 64-bit, my pc is a 64 bit one , does it matter or do i have to install a 64bit version ,

This is the error code i get after i try boot from one of the cd's I have burned
and after the Ubuntu logo appears

Enter `help` for list of build in commands

**(Initramfs) mounts:** `/mounting/dev/loop0` on `//` filesystem. **squashfs failed:**  **input/output error**

can not mount `/dev/loop0/ on`/cdrom/casrper/filesystem.squashfs`on`//` filesystem. squashfs

Any suggestions would be appreciated .

Comment: I have a NDVIDIA geforce gts 450

Comment: Also would it matter if you have dual hdd,s .

Comment: I type the sudo apt-get install nvidia-current  at the boot menu or while the ubuntu logo is on the screen . or when the computer justs dtarts up?

Comment: I wrote another cd , I am getting this error code of the windows disc image burner , 0*80004005,      so maybe its the download? might just order a cd from the website if i cant get it to work this way

Comment: Yeap that worked the NVIDIA driver install , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, to resolve the graphics problem on the wubi install

First,  after the computer boots, type ctrl-alt-f2 and log in. If you are unable to do that, boot to recovery mode and drop to a shell ("netroot" in the recovery menu).

See also [How to connect to internet from recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95266/how-to-connect-to-internet-from-recovery-mode)

You then install the nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And reboot.

If needed, to adjust your resolution, use `nvidia-setings`

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```