# Restore accidentally with rm'ed pam.conf?

Tags: sudo, privileges, pam

I have accidently removed the files `/etc/pam.conf` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`using `rm`.  Now I get this error message when I try to use sudo:

```
sudo: unable to initialize PAM: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copied the files '/etc/pam.conf' and '/etc/security/pam_env.conf' and the folder 'pam.d' from the Ubuntu Installation Disk.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall `libpam-runtime`:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libpam-runtime libpam-modules
```

If you can't use sudo, use [root shell in the recovery mode.](https://askubuntu.com/q/95266/169736) You must use wired connection and type:

```
apt-get --reinstall install libpam-runtime libpam-modules
```

You can use the root shell and copy the same file saved somewhere else copied from another system or purge the package and install it.

Comment: That seems to be a good idea. However, I cannot use sudo.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: pam-auth-update can help him for sure

Comment: I have reinstalled libpam-runtime, but it did not help. Then when I rebooted, as I suspected, I could not log in any more. Now I am using the LiveCD. I will try to copy the /etc/pam.conf from there.

Comment: @user203053 remember `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for: extundelete - utility to recover deleted files from ext3/ext4 partition

To find such a package, you can try:

`apt-cache search undelete`

To use the utility install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install extundelete
```

After installation [click here and read it carefully](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/extundelete.1.html)

For getting back sudo privileges create a file

```
pkexec gedit /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
```

and then just copy and paste these lines

```
session        [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session        requisite                       pam_deny.so
session        required                        pam_permit.so
session        required                        pam_unix.so
```

Save and exit , hope it works..

Comment: he said he can not use sudo

Comment: Thanks Sushantp606. But I got the problem: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized. I will try again in recovery mode.